# Merging several lists to create a data frame in R

Tags: r, list, merge

Apologies in advance if this has already been asked elsewhere, but I've tried different attempts and nothing has worked so far.

I study the data from 23 devices mesuring air pollution. For each device, I am interested in 4 parameters (mean, max, min and std). I finally obtain 4 lists with 23 values, representing the parameters for each device.

```
    var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^Device")
    Corrected_values<- mget(var_names)

    Device_mean <- lapply(Corrected_values, mean)
    Device_max <- lapply(Corrected_values, max)
    Device_min <- lapply(Corrected_values, min)
    Device_sd <- lapply(Corrected_values, sd)
```

Now I wish to create a data frame "Device" that will be a merge of these 4 lists. This data frame (or matrix) with 4 columns and 23 rows will then be exportable for further uses. Up to now, all my attempts resulted in a wrong matrix.

```
    # rename the column names
    cols <- c("Mean", "Maximum", "Minimum", "Stdv")
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: `data.frame(Device_mean, Device_max, Device_min, Device_sd)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way.

```
var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^Device")
Corrected_values <- mget(var_names)
f <- function(x){
  data.frame(Mean = mean(x), Maximum = max(x), Minimum = min(x), Stdv = sd(x))
}

do.call(rbind, Map(f, Corrected_values))
#         Mean Maximum Minimum      Stdv
#Device1 5.006     5.8     4.3 0.3524897
#Device2 6.588     7.9     4.9 0.6358796
#Device3 5.936     7.0     4.9 0.5161711
```

**Data**

```
Device1 <- iris[iris$Species == 'setosa', 'Sepal.Length']
Device2 <- iris[iris$Species == 'virginica', 'Sepal.Length']
Device3 <- iris[iris$Species == 'versicolor', 'Sepal.Length']
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what Rui Barradas proposes works but it appears to be because the

```
    f <- function(x){
      data.frame(Mean = mean(x), Maximum = max(x), Minimum = min(x), Stdv = sd(x))
    }
```

automatically recognizes what "Mean = mean(x), Maximum = max(x), Minimum = min(x), Stdv = sd(x)" means whitout using the 4 lists created beforehand in the script. 
Unfortunately, it does not work if I wish to add some other lists created. Indeed, now imagine I have 8 lists instead of the first 4 lists presented before:

```
var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^Device")
Corr_values<- mget(var_names)

Device_mean <- lapply(Corr_values, mean) #list 1
Device_max <- lapply(Corr_values, max) #list2
Device_min <- lapply(Corr_values, min) #list3
Device_sd <- lapply(Corr_values, sd) #list4

hours_per_year <- 365*24
multiply <- function(x, factor) {
x * hours_per_year}
Device_average_annual_dose <- lapply(Device_mean, multiply, factor = hours_per_year) #list5

var_names_dates <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^Date")
Corr_dates<- mget(var_names_dates)
Device_hours_with_values <- lapply(Corr_dates, length) #list6

a <- (100/hours_per_year)
multiply <- function(x, factor) {
x * a}
Device_availability <- lapply(Device_hours_with_values, multiply, factor = a) #list7

subtract_me = 100
Device_unavailability <- lapply(Device_availability, function(x, subt_amnt) subt_amnt - x,subt_amnt = subtract_me) #list8
```

These 8 lists are correctly stored in R. but in this case, when I try what you propose to me to merge the 8 lists by using the 8 list names, I receive the error message:

```
    Error in max(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I do not understand because these are precisely some lists that I whish to merge...